# Java Version Problem

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk

Ubuntu version: 16.04
I was using the Java 11 last times and also I have java 11 on my computer. Somehow reason some program doesnt work with java 11 so I decide the remove it but. It doesnt remove I get lots of error. For example when I enter below code:

```
echo $PATH
/home/duygu/bin /home/duygu/.local/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /snap/bin /home/duygu/bin /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin
```

I get this path but I dont have jdk-11.0.8 file, I remove from usr/lib/jvm/

I tried this:

```
sudo vi /etc/environment
```

get this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
```

And when I open this file:

```
sudo vim /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
```

I get this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

EDIT:
When I try this:
source /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh
I get:
s

```
et: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/duygu/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/duygu/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/duygu/.local/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/duygu/.local/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/sbin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/sbin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/sbin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /sbin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/games may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/games'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/local/games may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/games'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/snap/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /snap/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/home/duygu/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /home/duygu/bin'?
set: Warning: path component usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin may not be valid in PATH.
set: No such file or directory
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.8/bin'?
```

Where is my problem. How can I remove totaly java 11 and install java 8 ?

Comment: I think its unsolving problem :/

Comment: Can you share /etc/profile.d/jdk.sh file? Is it created by you? try placing /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 between quotes like this "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

Comment: jdk.sh file include:
export JAVA_HOME=usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Comment: I added some new detail

Comment: Does bin folder exist in usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 ?

Comment: yes bin file exist in there

Comment: It's strange. I'm unable to find the issue. You might wanna wait for someone who's more experienced than me.

Comment: topic updated..